# Trigger workflow n hours before a date field

Tags: workflow, date

I am trying to schedule a workflow to send an email alert 52 hours before a class starts. Class is held at the same time every day (2pm) it's offered and therefore class_date was set up as a Date field.

For time-based triggers for workflows on Date fields, what time do the fire (can I assume 00:00)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't assume at what time it will fire because date/time is calculated at the time when workflow is fired. So it would be wrong to assume anything.

For example I created on time based workflow on my **Account** object which will fire after 30 days of `CreatedDate`. When I saw it's entry in Time Based Workflow it was something like this:

[image]

It has taken the count of 30 days right from the `createdDate` including it's time.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I agree on a date/time field (and there looks to be a delay on a date field - not sure how this can vary, though). I'll do some evaluating on whether this impacts my users and if so will change the field to date/time.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to demonstrate this on a Date field (not date/time) will fire "X" hours before the date field I am looking at. It looks at 3/29/2017 as equivalent to 3/29/2017 00:00 when *scheduling*.

[image]

All classes start at 2pm and we want the message sent at 10am (or so) 2 days beforehand, so setting this to 52 hours before should do the trick (assuming we're not over our email allotment). The workflow in the picture above actually fired 12 minutes after it was scheduled, which is close enough.